# AES algorithm in C# - Totally confused over now

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I initially scavenged(Google,SO,Bing) for a working code showing how to encrypt and decrypt password's using the AES algorithm available in .NET using c#. My doubts arise from these two posts

1. http://yossi-yakubov.blogspot.in/2010/07/aes-encryption-using-c-short-way.html
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx

in **#1** he shows that everything could be done using the `CryptoTransform` but the `MSDN` page sample shows use of complex streams.

- Do i need to do that?
- What benefits do i have one over the other?
- Could someone clarify which is best code i need to follow and any caveats in other methods.

adding to the confusion **[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14497/Data-Encryption-Decryption-using-RijndaelManaged-a)** post talks about salt's in encryption , now i am totally lost.Why should salt's be present in encryption rather than HASHING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches work, but I would say that the method used in the first of your links is best for "small" amounts of data, where the data can fit reasonably within the input `byte[]` (e.g. keys, passwords etc.).

The method from the second link is better suited to "large" amounts of data, where loading the entire input into memory may be infeasible, and a streaming approach is more suitable (e.g. encrypting a file or data on a network stream).

Given your needs, the method from the first link is probably appropriate.

As for the mention of a salt in your final link, this is only being used to seed `PasswordDeriveBytes`, and is not directly related to the AES algorithm itself.

It is worth mentioning however that there is a "salt" of sorts for AES as well in the form of the IV (initialization vector). This is simply random data (which should be different every time), that can be stored alongside the ciphertext, and ensures that even when encrypting the same data multiple times, the output is different.

With this in mind, the method shown in the final link should *not* be used, as it appears to produce the same output every time, because both the key and the IV are generated entirely from the password entered, whereas the IV should instead be random bytes.

Comment: wonderfully explained now everything makes sense.btw just a quirk does base64encoding, decoding, utf8 encoding,decoding baked inside the methods that decrypt,encrypt the raw data or outside.I put them outside so future developers can implement their own way of storing the `byte[]` after encryption. for example this is thing followed now `DAL.ChangePassword(Convert.ToBase64String(AESUtility.EncryptPassword(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password),KEY,IV)));`

Comment: I think I personally would pass strings to the method, and expect Base64 string output (thus putting UTF8.GetBytes and Convert.ToBase64String inside the encrypt method). The rationale being that it reduces the overhead of having to have those conversions everywhere the method is used, and also ensures that it's standard and (almost) guarantees that a password encryption written by one developer can be decrypted by another without having to determine what conversions they may have used when encrypting.

Comment: The core crypto libraries already handle keys and binary data. You should not create wrapper methods around them that do the same thing; instead, focus on your use case and create classes for those.